# Ideavim Folding and Expanding Code Blocks

Tags: vim, intellij-plugin, ideavim

What is the key binding for folding and expanding code blocks in **ideavim** plugin ?

(***za*** works in  **vrapper** for eclipse , but not in ideavim )

Answer (score 49, accepted):

source : [ideavim help: fold](http://ideavim.sourceforge.net/vim/fold.html)

**zo**              Open one fold under the cursor.  When a count is given, that
                many folds deep will be opened.  In Visual mode one level of
                folds is opened for all lines in the selected area.

**zc**              Close one fold under the cursor.  When a count is given, that
                many folds deep are closed.  In Visual mode one level of folds
                is closed for all lines in the selected area.
                'foldenable' will be set.

**zM**              Close all folds: set 'foldlevel' to 0.
                'foldenable' will be set.

**zR**              Open all folds.  This sets 'foldlevel' to highest fold level.

Comment: Hi @amin Do I understand the help correctly link? There's no support for zm and zr, which increases and decreases foldlevel? https://neovim.io/doc/user/fold.html

Would you know where can we request this feature? or is there an ideavim pragmatic appoach for changing the buffer's fold level.

Answer (score 10):

Adding these lines to your ~/.ideavimrc allows the **zO** and **zC** commands, which recursively open and close the folds under the cursor:

```
nnoremap zC :action CollapseRegionRecursively<CR>
nnoremap zO :action ExpandRegionRecursively<CR>
```

I find these to be super-helpful in vim, and was missing them when using PyCharm with IdeaVim.
(HT: https://github.com/JetBrains/ideavim/pull/97 )